# How to import modules in Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-worker

I'm developing project using Node.js + TypeScript.

After launching main.ts it returns:

```
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

*main.ts*

```
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';

const worker = new Worker('./src/Workers/worker.ts');

worker.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
})

worker.postMessage('start');
```

*worker.ts*

```
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
import { broadcastService } from '../services/BroadcastService'

parentPort?.on('message', async (data: string) => {
    console.log(data);
    const currentBroadcasts = await broadcastService.startBroadcastsChecking();
    parentPort?.postMessage(currentBroadcasts);
})
```

Tried:

1. changing file extension to `.js` (*worker.ts -> worker.js*)
2. `new Worker('./src/Workers/broadcastsCheckingWorker.ts', { type: 'module' } as any)` (*main.ts*)

```
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

3. `importScripts('../services/BroadcastService')` (*worker.js/worker.ts*)

```
importScripts('../services/BroadcastService')
^
ReferenceError [Error]: importScripts is not defined
```

4. adding `"type": "module"` to package.json

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\lives-downloader-bot\src\server.ts
```